# Primes $p$ such that $\gcd(a,p-1)=1\implies a^{p-1}\bmod(p-1)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the primes $p$ such that $\gcd(a,p-1)=1\implies a^{p-1}\bmod(p-1)=1$.

This is many, but not all primes. The smallest exception is $p=11\,$: notice $3^{10}\bmod10=9\ne1$.

I noticed that the first few $p$ coincide with [A138539](https://oeis.org/A138539); or the union of $2$ and [A058341](https://oeis.org/A058341), with the later being primes $p$ such that $\varphi(x)=p-1$ has more than 2 solutions.

I formerly asked: Does this generalize? Why?

---

On closer examination: no. The first exception is $p=89$, $a=3$.

A better characterization is [given](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/7813661) by Daniel Fischer: primes $p$ such that $\lambda(p-1)$ divides $p-1$. The first few are

```
2 3 5 7 13 17 19 37 41 43 61 73 97 101 109 127 157 163 181 193 241 257 313 337 379 401 421 433 487 541 577 601 641 661 673 757 769 881 883 937 1009 1093 1153 1201 1249 1297 1321 1361 1459 1601 1621 1801 1861 1873
```

Experimentally, the density of such primes thins out. **How fast?**

Comment: Generally, "$\gcd(a,n) = 1 \implies a^n \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$" means $\lambda(n) \mid n$, where $\lambda$ is the Carmichael function. So you're looking for primes $p$ such that $\lambda(p-1) \mid p-1$. I don't know whether that observation helps.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: $\lambda(p-1) \mid p-1$ gives a direct way to characterize $p$ when $p-1$ is of known factorization; so that's useful.

Comment: These numbers seem to be called Novak–Carmichael numbers, and you are looking for the subset of them that are of the form $p-1$.